# Setting up "Become a Legend" mode

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2011

I'm kinda disappointed by the gameplay of "Become a Legend" mode in PES 11. I'll explain why: I have Fifa 10 on my Xbox and I've played with the "same" mode in there but it's really different.

What I'm saying is that in Fifa 10 I control only my player but I can call a pass, a cross etc...in PES I can't do any of that and sometimes the AI of PES it's not really quick in completing a passage or doing something trickier like a 1-2 (that's the term we use in Italy, basically I pass the ball to you and you pass to me the ball back).
In Fifa 10 I can do this because I can call the action (and if it's not completed I lose points). Is possible to obtain something like that in PES 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(EDIT: it's R1, not L1)

Double "click" R1 (RB on Xbox I think) to ask for the ball.  Whether you get it or not depends on how high is your team work.  You may be able to get a 1-2 this way.

Please note, that the player may not pass the ball right away, or maybe he'll pass to somebody else, who'll try to pass it to you.  If your team work is high enough he'll try to pass it even when it's obvious that it'll be intercepted by opposing player.

Also, the pass is *always* made on the ground, so if you wan't a cross *don't* call for the ball.

I am a PES fan and haven't played FIFA's mode, but I think BAL sucks.  I really hope they'll do something about it in PES 2012.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it. In FIFA's mode you have more control than on BAL but I guess in BAL it makes sense that you can't call everything. In FIFA the system is really simple, it's not complex like in BAL.